# android app scanning before press start

Tags: android

I have also posted in android Enthusiasts, not sure if its the correct place..

We have created an app to scan for wifi hotspots / AP so we can read the SSID and RSSI. We have some test phones with hotspot turned on and hard coded the SSID into the app. When the APP launches for the first time all works OK, we click the AP (checkbox) and hit start (button).When we close the app and launch it again, as soon as we click the AP (checkbox) it start scanning even though we haven't click the start button. we need to reinstall the app on the phone every time. Can anyone help us with this BUG/ unwanted feature as its slowing us up.

here is the code for the main Activity.

your help is greatly appreciated.

```
    public class RssiMyActivity extends Activity{
    // Declare global variables
    private WifiManager mainWifiObj;
    private WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private List<String> ap_details = new ArrayList<String>();

    private static String ssid;
    private int testCount;
    private CheckBox a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rssi_my);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    // Get make a connection to database to get test count
    ReceiveFromDB receiver = new ReceiveFromDB();
    receiver.execute();

    // Update the test count
    testCount = ReceiveFromDB.getCount();
    testCount += 1;

    // Check to see what value testCount is
    Log.e("Values for testCount", String.valueOf(testCount));

    Button start;
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Timer added to get new scan result once every 2 seconds
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();

            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    TimerMethod();
                }
            }, 0, 4000);
        }
    });

    Button pause;
    pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            onPause();
        }
    });

    Button resume;
    resume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);
    resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            onResume();
        }
    });

    a1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.AP1);
    a2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.AP2);
    a3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.AP3);
    a4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.AP4);
    a5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.AP5);
    a6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.AP6);
}

protected void onPause()
{
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume()
{
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}

// Timer method to run at the same time as the main activity
private void TimerMethod()
{
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

/*
 * Runnable method add code to here to refresh at specified time
 */
private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // start a scan of ap's
            mainWifiObj.startScan();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
    {
        // Clear details to refresh the screen for each new scan
        if (ap_details.size() > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                ap_details.clear();
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            // Get all Objects from the scan
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
            List<ScanResult> temp = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();

            // Run through each signal and retrieve the mac ssid rssi
            for (ScanResult aWifiScanList : wifiScanList)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                // Pull out the info we need
                ssid = aWifiScanList.SSID;

                // Check which ap's are selected
                if (checkDisplay())
                {
                    // Add info to StringBuilder
                    sb.append(aWifiScanList.SSID).append("\n");
                    sb.append(String.valueOf(aWifiScanList.level)).append("\n");
                    sb.append("Test: ").append(String.valueOf(testCount)).append("\n");

                    // Add to List that will be displayed to user
                    ap_details.add(sb.toString());

                    // Also add to a temporary ScanResult List to use later
                    temp.add(aWifiScanList);
                }
            }

            // Create an String Array twice the size of the temporary
            // ScanResult
            // this will be the Array to use as the parameters for sending
            // to the database
            String[] items = new String[temp.size() + temp.size() + 1];

            int num1 = 0;
            int num2 = 1;

            // Add the ssid and rssi of each object to the Array
            for (ScanResult aTemp : temp)
            {
                items[num1] = aTemp.SSID;
                items[num2] = String.valueOf(aTemp.level);

                num1 += 2;
                num2 += 2;
            }

            // Add the test value
            items[num1] = String.valueOf(testCount);

            // Pass Array to the Async method use executeOnExecutor this
            // allows for the use
            // of the Looper.prepare() method to stop app from crashing
            new ConnectToDB().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, items);

            // Display the list of all the signals on the device
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ap_details);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Method to check which AP's are been used
 */
public boolean checkDisplay()
{
    if (a1.isChecked())
    {
        if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("TestPhone1"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (a2.isChecked())
    {
        if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("TestPhone2"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (a3.isChecked())
    {
        if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("TestPhone3"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (a4.isChecked())
    {
        if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("TestPhone4"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (a5.isChecked())
    {
        if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("TestPhone5"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (a6.isChecked())
    {
        if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("TestPhone6"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok got it working, not sure if its the right way but its working ok. I just unregister the reciecer and register it again by calling the two methods "onPause() and onResume()" one after the other and just before the startScan() method. see code:

```
private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // unRegister Receiver wifiReciever
            onPause();
            // register Receiver wifiReciever
            onResume();

            // start a scan of ap's
            mainWifiObj.startScan();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

would love to know if this is correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You never call cancel() on your timer task to remove it from the Timer scheduler. Try inserting that in a button you use to stop it from scanning.

If that doesn't work, try calling cancel() on the timer itself.

Comment: I dont have a button on the app for stopping, might add one. This problem happens when I close the app and then launch again.